# quiero usar foreach, find y spread operator para hacer una función pero no he podido

Tags: javascript, html, foreach, map, find

Tengo el array `listacompradepurada`, quiero que tome cada elemento de ese array y lo busque en el array `listaPrecios`, cuando lo encuentre que vea  si `promoción === true`, en ese momento hace otro  poco de cosas pero para el caso puse que devuelva el mensaje "lo logré" pero no sé que  estoy usando mal porque se queda todo el tiempo en el primer valor

```js
let listaCompradepurada = [{
    cod_articulo: 'C',
    cantidad: 2,

},
{
    cod_articulo: 'D',
    cantidad: 5,

},

{
    cod_articulo: 'B',
    cantidad: 1,

},

];

let listaPrecios = [{
    cod_articulo: 'C',
    cantidad: 2,
    promocion: `true`,

},
{
    cod_articulo: 'D',
    cantidad: 5,
    promocion: `false`,

},

{
    cod_articulo: 'B',
    cantidad: 1,
    promocion: `true`,

},

];

listaCompradepurada.forEach(iterador => {
    const equivalente = listaCompradepurada.find(articulo => articulo.codigo === listaPrecios.articulo);
    if (equivalente) {
        return [...listaCompradepurada.articulo, listaPrecios.promocion];

    }
    if (listaCompradepurada.promocion === `true`) {
        console.log(`lo logré`);

    }
})
```

Comment: ¿ `articulo.codigo`? ¿Donde está la propiedad llamada `codigo`? En todo caso `articulo.cod_articulo` o  `articulo['.cod_articulo']`.

Comment: si, tienes razón, es articulo.cod_articulo

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que lo que quieres es esto (más abajo verás otra posible respuesta con **map**):

```js
let listaCompradepurada = [{
    cod_articulo: 'C',
    cantidad: 2,
  },
  {
    cod_articulo: 'D',
    cantidad: 5,
  },

  {
    cod_articulo: 'B',
    cantidad: 1,
  },
];

let listaPrecios = [{
    cod_articulo: 'C',
    cantidad: 2,
    promocion: `true`,
  },
  {
    cod_articulo: 'D',
    cantidad: 5,
    promocion: `false`,
  },

  {
    cod_articulo: 'B',
    cantidad: 1,
    promocion: `true`,
  },
];

listaCompradepurada.forEach(iterador => {
  const equivalente = listaPrecios.find(element => element.cod_articulo === iterador.cod_articulo)
  if (equivalente) {
    console.log([...iterador.cod_articulo, equivalente.promocion])
  }
  if (equivalente.promocion === `true`) {
    console.log(`lo logré`);
  }
})
```

**Cambios realizados:**

1. Donde ponias esto:

```javascript
const equivalente = listaCompradepurada.find(articulo => articulo.codigo === listaPrecios.articulo);
```

ahora he puesto esto:

```javascript
const equivalente = listaPrecios.find(element => element.cod_articulo === iterador.cod_articulo)
```

porque lo que pretendias era buscar en `listaPrecios` el mismo valor que el elemento iterado en cada ciclo de `listaCompradepurada`, representado por **iterador**.  También, como te han dicho en los comentarios, he usado **cod_articulo** que es la propiedad comun a ambos objetos, en lugar de *codigo* o *articulo* que ponias erroneamente.

2. Donde ponías esto:

```javascript
return [...listaCompradepurada.articulo, listaPrecios.promocion];
```

lo he modificado por esto:

```javascript
console.log([iterador.cod_articulo, equivalente.promocion])
```

porque un **return** allí no tenia sentido, el [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) no es una función que espere un retorno como podria ser [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Del mismo modo he quitado la sintaxis [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) porque no se espera ese retorno, y lo he dejado en un **console.log()** para que se muestre en consola como entra en el condicional **if**.

### Otra respuesta con map()

Como no estoy seguro de si la respuesta de arriba es lo que pretendias, y parecias empeñado en usar la sintaxis de spread, forEach y find, a continuación te muestro otro snippet que quizás te sirva, donde, aparte de algunos cambios coincidentes con lo explicado anteriormente, he cambiado el **forEach** por **map**, dejando el *return* y modificando el orden de los condicionales para que se pueda mostrar el "Lo logré", que debido al *return* de la otra forma no se mostraba al ejecutarse antes de poder llegar al segundo condicional.

En este caso te acaba devolviendo un array que contiene los otros tres arrays creados durante los ciclos.

```js
let listaCompradepurada = [{
    cod_articulo: 'C',
    cantidad: 2,
  },
  {
    cod_articulo: 'D',
    cantidad: 5,
  },

  {
    cod_articulo: 'B',
    cantidad: 1,
  },
];

let listaPrecios = [{
    cod_articulo: 'C',
    cantidad: 2,
    promocion: `true`,
  },
  {
    cod_articulo: 'D',
    cantidad: 5,
    promocion: `false`,
  },

  {
    cod_articulo: 'B',
    cantidad: 1,
    promocion: `true`,
  },
];

const result = listaCompradepurada.map(iterador => {
  const equivalente = listaPrecios.find(element => element.cod_articulo === iterador.cod_articulo)
  if (equivalente.promocion === `true`) {
    console.log(`lo logré:` + iterador.cod_articulo);
  }
  if (equivalente) {
    return [...iterador.cod_articulo, equivalente.promocion]
  }
})
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Con tu codigo como busca los que cumplen seria mas claro mostrarlo como:`const cumplen=[]
listaCompradepurada.forEach(iterador => {
  const equivalente = listaPrecios.find
  (element => element.cod_articulo === iterador.cod_articulo)
  if (equivalente.promocion === `true`) {
      console.log(`lo logré cumple:`,iterador)
     cumplen.push(iterador)
     
  }
})
 console.log(`lo logré cumplen :`,cumplen)`

Comment: @nestdan , gracias por el aporte, lo que pide el op es conseguir ver el "lo logré" que acabo de modificar un poco para que se muestre al menos el código de artículo.

Comment: Si ahora cuando lo encuentra muestra lo logre gracias

Comment: Ya lo hacia antes tambien, pero no decia donde... y se me habia quedado un console.log() de más (que era para mi depuración) que podia estar confundiendote pero que ya he borrado y ahora todo queda más claro, gracias.

Comment: muchas gracias, lo del map lo consideré pero realmente no se requiere el tercer array.

Comment: Si esta respuesta te ha servido para solucionar tu pregunta deberias marcarla como aceptada para que la comunidad lo vea cuando entren a consultar lo mismo o parecido. En este [enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) aprenderás a aceptar respuestas válidas y porque es importante. También te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y colaborar con el, gracias!